# Предзагрузка файла php через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть строка в htaccess, которая первым загружает php файл:

**php_value auto_prepend_file "./test/index.php"**

Это не работает на некоторых страницах сайта. Если зайти по адресу site.ru/test/index.php то это не работает.
Подскажите, какой код написать в .htaccess, чтобы правильно предзагрузить php файл на любых страницах сайта. Нужно конкретно htaccess

Comment: Попробовал абсолютный путь, так получилось:

php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/u/user/site/public_html/test/index.php"

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно чего Вы хотите этим добиться, если нужно подключить файл то почему не:

```
require_once
```

или

```
include_once
```

Если же хотите сделать единую точку входа, тогда так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: require_once и include_once не подходит, пробовал. Описанная вами единая точка входа уже имеется. Мне нужно перед ней(перед index.php), в самом начале "впрыгнуть в тапочки" и проверить соответствие параметров. Так получилось: php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/u/user/site/public_html/test/index.php"

Comment: @Сергей, Что мешает подключить скрипт в начале index.php? Логика не понятна вообще!

Comment: Специфика скрипта предназначена для разных сайтов, если это cms с возможностью обновлений, вероятность потерять подключение больше чем с htaccess. Также иногда в cms есть две точки входа, уже менее удобно.